# Want Dynamic Grid in Angular 8 using Material design

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want a dynamic Grid in Angular 8, can someone guild me way to achieve below Grid using two Objects.

```
var Obj1=    {
    "Bullets": [
        {
            "name": "Bullet1",
            "DD_Rapid": 10,
            "II_Rapid": 30
        },
        {
            "name": "Bullet2",
            "DD_Rapid": 40,
            "II_Rapid": 40
        }
    ]
}

var Obj2= {
    "setting": {
        "DD_Rapid": {
            "name": "DELD Rapid",
            "fontColor": "blue",
            "backColor": "red"
        },
        "II_Rapid": {
            "name": "Jumbo Rapid",
            "fontColor": "blue",
            "backColor": "red"
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Can someone advice me on this.

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

Comment: I've written a series on the mattable: https://dev.to/jwp/angular-material-table-in-20-minutes-15f4